# Sinon.js spy on a class constructor returns false, even though the constructor is called

Tags: node.js, sinon, chai

I am trying sinon.js for the first time and this is a piece of code that I am trying to test:

```
class ErrorWithStatusCode extends Error{
    constructor(code, message, err){
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
        this.error = err;
    }
}

export {ErrorWithStatusCode}
```

and this is my test file

```
import {ErrorWithStatusCode} from '../../handlers/error.handler';
import chai from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
const should = chai.should();
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('Error Class', ()=>{
    it('the contructor function should be called once', ()=>{
        const spyFunc = sinon.spy(ErrorWithStatusCode, 'constructor');
        const err = new ErrorWithStatusCode(500, 'Sorry, some error occurred.', {message: 'Some error'});
        console.log(err);
        expect(spyFunc.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    })
});
```

But, my test fails, even though `err` contains the error object.

Comment: Not really sure what this test is trying to accomplish? It looks like you're trying to verify you called the function that you just mocked? You don't need to mock the constructor; call it and check that the returned object has the properties set on it that you passed in as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Stubbing a class `constructor` is not possible in `Sinon`.

From a maintainer of the `Sinon` project:

> the constructor keyword in ES6 classes is just syntactic sugar. You still need to actually test for invocations of the function creating the class, not its constructor property.

---

Link: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/831#issuecomment-209648966